# 40th derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives, power-series, solution-verification

I would like to have some verification to see if my answer is correct. The given function is $f(x)=ln(1+x^2)$ and I need the 40th derivative at $x=0$. Here is my work: Using series one can manipulate $\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4...=SUMx^n(-1)^n$ into $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8...=SUMx^{2n}(-1)^n$. Then $\frac{2x}{1+x}=2x-2x^3+2x^5-2x^7+2x^9...=2SUMx^{2n+1}(-1)^n$. Integrating gives $ln(1+x^2)=...=2SUM\frac{x^{2n+2}(-1)^n}{2n+2}$ where a $2$ cancels to arrive at a $n+1$ in that denominator. Now for the 40th derivative, $2n+2=40$ gives $n=19$ and thus I believe the answer is $\frac{-40!}{20}$ Do you concur? If not could you correct me? Thanks.

Comment: Why a downvote without an explanation?

Comment: seems god to me.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to be certain....

Comment: This question is unsuitable to answered. One sentence answers belong in the comment section, thus this question can't be answered. This would be different if your proof was wrong ;)

Comment: @Zach466920 I am posting my work with my question. If people post questions without any effort, then naturally the bloggers are not going to do the work for the OP. But I am showing my work and I would like to be sure that what I am doing is right. What's unsuitable about that? The worst you can say is about my poor formatting for which I apologize

Comment: @imranfat You've failed to read my comment. Showing your work is irrelevant, any answer posted should be a comment, thus your question is unanswerable...

Comment: @Zach466920 your comment is not relevent imo. downvoting this question is silly.

Comment: @mookid imo this question has been answered already, but not with an actual additional posting. Thus this question should be closed, as it is not applicable to a larger audience. (Of course I realize most will only read the first comment, find *me* to be in the wrong, up vote the answer and never realize that Op is garnering rep for a trivial question). No offense Op, this isn't about rep farming.

Comment: @Zach466920: Wait--what? Are you saying that if the question can be answered in one sentence, it should be closed instead of answered?

Comment: @MPW I'm saying that if the answer is not applicable to a large audience, which could be due to its shortness, the question should be closed. In this case, the question is highly specific and garners a one sentence response that is not particularly illuminating to future readers.

Comment: The "large" in my above comment should be changed to "larger". I don't believe there is a viewing quota on this site ;)

Comment: @Zach466920: In view of some of the gibberish that slops onto this forum, I would say this is a welcome relief and a fine example of a well-posed question. It exhibits evidence of effort, a clear explanation of what was attempted, a markedly mature grasp of style, and a complete absence of the meandering guesswork that one often sees. If only we saw this more often!

Comment: @MPW I'm not criticizing his style, I'm saying the question can help no one except Op. Considering that finding the 30th, 50th, etc derivatives could be made into questions, the only version that should be here is finding the nth derivative.

Comment: @MPW BTW This site is NOT a forum...

Comment: @Zach466920 Look, you need to understand few things here. I am not looking for reps or stars for that matter. I am a mathematician in the teaching field and never done with learning myself. Sometimes I answer a question if I believe I can help the OP, sometimes I post a question because I have no answer or because I ask few mathies just to double check before I use it in my lectures. It's simple as that. I am grateful to those who confirm/correct my answer. So far, your contribution is nothing but engaging in a useless discussion, so chill and be helpful, because it's better for all of us

Comment: @imranfat you obviously did not read my comment were I specifically said this has nothing to do with rep farming or your contributions....Do you notice you still have no answer? You think I do nothing except engage in childish arguments??? I'll remind you that your answer has already been answered, and suggest that you delete the question. Due to your ad-hominim approach, I'd prefer not to continue discussion.

Comment: @Zach466920 Mookid gave me a confirmation of my work I was looking for. For me that's an answer. You don't agree, that's your problem. There is no reason for me to delete the post. MPW is trying to teach you something in this thread, but in vain. Next time when I post my work for verification, I will be thankful to those who are willing to look at it and give me their ok. I hope you won't be one of them. Mind you, you do not own MathStack Exchange. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the $40$th derivative at 0 will yield you the coefficient for the $x^{40}$ term multiplied by $40!$

The general series for natural log is:

$$
ln(x+1) = \frac {x^1}1 - \frac {x^2}2 + \frac {x^3}3 - \frac {x^4}4...
$$

replacing $x^2$ makes:

$$
ln(x^2+1) = \frac {x^2}1 - \frac {x^4}2 + \frac {x^6}3 - \frac {x^8}4...
$$

From this it is apparent that the 20th term of the first series shares its coefficient with the 40th term of the second series.

The coefficient equals $-\frac 1{20}$. Multiplying $40!$ to cancel the implied division yields: $-\frac {40!}{20}$

From this I confirm your answer to be correct; however, your proof and solution is incredibly messy. There is a known series for natural log. Using a fractional series and integrating was a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Hmmm, first taking an anti derivative and then replacing the $x$ by $x^2$ is indeed much faster. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, but that ln series came from the geometric series...

Comment: Indeed it was discovered that way. Actually quite a lot of series stuff (and sums) was discovered after "exhausting" possibilities of what one can do with geometric series. I remember I learned the series of $ln(1+x)$ as well as $ln(1-x)$ back in the 17th/18th century that way. I do agree that all these standard series ought to be remembered by heart, but that counts for series for $sinx$ , $cosx$ and all the other "standard" transcendental functions as well. I guess I am a dinosaur here, communicating with a great duck :)